# How to I select individual characters out of a sting and replace them with another [Python 3]?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For example:

```
aStr = input("Please input: ")
```

Something that turns all A chatacters in aStr into 4 characters, or a into @ etc.
(What would I use here? I know `string.strip` and `string.translate` seem to have 2 arguments but only solves one and that's a little beyond me... I'm a novice).

```
print("Your output is: " +aStr)
```

Comment: you want "A" to be replaced by 4 characters that you specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `string` object has a `replace` method. You can do something like this:

```
>>> x = 'Hello world'
>>> x.replace('l', '@')
'He@@o wor@d'

>>> help(str.replace)
Help on method_descriptor:

replace(...)
    S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str

    Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
    given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

You can also access individual characters via indexing, like `x[0]`, but note that strings are immutable in Python, so you cannot assign to characters.

```
>>> x[0]='p'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2cb5a895cce7> in <module>()
----> 1 x[0]='p'

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

**EDIT:** Replacing every other occurrence is a bit trickier, and I can't think of a good one-liner at the moment, but this *verbose* and slightly *un-pythonic* function will do:

```
import re

def replace_every_nth(mystring, oldstr, newstr, nth):
    parts = re.split('(%s)' % oldstr, mystring)
    partcount = 1
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        if parts[i] == oldstr:
            if partcount % nth == 0:
                parts[i] = newstr
            partcount += 1
    return ''.join(parts)

>>> replace_every_nth(x, 'l', '@', 1)
'He@@o wor@d'

>>> replace_every_nth(x, 'l', '@', 2)
'Hel@o world'

>>> replace_every_nth(x, 'l', '@', 3)
'Hello wor@d'

>>> replace_every_nth(x, 'll', '@', 3)
'Hello world'

>>> replace_every_nth(x, 'll', '@', 1)
>>> 'He@o world'

>>> replace_every_nth(x, 'lll', '@', 1)
>>> 'Hello world'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is REALLY helpful for me. I see you wrote about indexing, might you have any idea how to replace every other, every third, every fourth etc. so like Hello World --> Hel@o World

Answer (score 1):

`string.replace()` is deprecated in Python 3.x so you could use `str.replace()` or `re.sub()`

Using `replace` is simpler than using regex and will be fine for most simple-use scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

```
aStr = input("Please input: ")

print("Your output is: " + aStr.replace("A","@@@@"))
```

If you want to change upper or lowercase A/a

```
aStr = input("Please input: ")

if "A" in aStr:
    print("Your output is: " + aStr.replace("A","@@@@"))
elif "a" in aStr:
    print("Your output is: " + aStr.replace("a","@@@@"))
```